# How to save resource files(resx) to the drive

Tags: c#, resources

I want save a file to C drive, the user will select any locations to save the file. i have tried this code below and it is giving me an error on the line in bold. can you please correct me were am wrong. i also want to check if the file exist before saving. how can i do that?

this is the error am getting verify that the correct path was given

```
      string PathSelection = "";
            if (PathSelection.Length > 0)
            {
                txtInputfile.Text = PathSelection;
            }
            // i tried this
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Resource Files";
            saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "resx";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Save Resource Files (*.resx)|*.resx";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // error here!
            {
                PathSelection = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                //string path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                oDataSet.WriteXml(PathSelection);
            }

            oDataSet.Tables.Add("Data");
```

Comment: Error:verify that the correct path was given

Comment: Do you have the `using System.Windows.Forms;` directive added in your class?

Comment: using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Resources;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is odd:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
```

As you are trying to set to the initial directory for the dialog to show a filename that has not yet been selected by the user. Try taking this line out?

Regarding checking the file exists, the line you have added:

```
saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
```

This will check to make sure that the file you have specified exists, which is why you are getting the error you are getting. If you remove this line, you can then check to see if you are overwriting a file or creating a new one using:

```
 if(System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
```

Comment: I have remove the that line and still getting the same error : verify that the correct file name was given

Comment: i had put a break point to see were it is breaking if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, I've amended the answer, but basically you just need to remove the saveFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true; line then you won't get the error anymore

Comment: Awesome! working now. can i ask one more question. i have read resx file which get loaded on the gridview. now i want the user to be able to edit from the grid and click save button which will save it as a new file? how do i do that?

Comment: code too long can you please reply to my email sitholimela.eno@gmail.com

Comment: Please mark as an answer if it solved your problem. I suggest you post your other question onto Stack Overflow as well. If I see it I'll reply!